# Trying to connect mysql.connector python with pip, how to fix the error?

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

[image: pip install mysql-connector-python, and "Requirement already satisfied"]

Already tried to update pip, but nothing came of it. Why doesn't "pip install mysql-connector-python" command work?

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Comment: Looks like it worked just fine. What makes you think it _didn't_ work?

Comment: The problem is that when trying to import mysql.connector in a file visual studio interpreter shows that it is not defined.

Comment: Then you should ask about _that_. (But there are already dozens of questions about how to install libraries in to the correct environment.)